# SQL Server - Compare Fields in 2 Tables with PIVOT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, unpivot, sql-server-2019

I have the same table in two databases (`dbSource` and `dbTarget`) and I'm trying to write a query to compare the field values in each table with a Source/Target diff.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblWidget](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblWidget] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

For simplicity, I'll say the table in each database has one row:

`[dbSource]`:

[image: Source DB record]

`[dbTarget]`:

[image: Target DB record]

I want the result to look like this:

[image: Expected Result]

The closest I could get to the result is a `PIVOT` query that only returns one of the fields (`UpdatedBy`).
Is there a simple way to include all of the fields in one query vs. doing some kind of `UNION` with multiple `PIVOT` statements?

I realize if there is more than one row (example: a row with ID = 2), the expected results won't make sense, so please assume I will only be comparing one row between databases.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 'UpdatedBy' Field, [0] AS [Source], [1] AS [Target]
FROM
(
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[UpdatedBy]
      ,1 IsSource
FROM [dbSource].[dbo].[tblWidget]
UNION ALL 
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[UpdatedBy]
      ,0 IsSource
FROM [dbTarget].[dbo].[tblWidget]
) a
PIVOT (
    MAX(UpdatedBy)
    FOR IsSource IN ([0], [1])
) AS pvt
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for what can be given in text. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the two tables, and then unpivot the columns to rows:

```
select s.id, x.*
from dbsource.tblWidget s
inner join dbtarget.tblWidget t on t.id = s.id
cross apply (values 
    ('Description', s.description, t.description),
    ('UpdatedBy',   s.updatedby,   t.updatedby)
) x (field, source, target)
```

This assumes that column `id` can be used to relate the two tables - as a consequence, it does not make sense having a row for `id` in the result (both the source and target values always are the same).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Only edit to make it work with the original example is to use `.dbo` after `dbSource` and `dbTarget`.